# whats the error in creating this sql server view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting an error incorrect syntax near the key word 'view'

```
if object_id('my_view') is null 
 BEGIN
create view dbo.my_view as
select * from dbo.my_table;
 END
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to conditionally drop the view if it exists, and then the create need not be conditional, and you will guarantee the latest version of the view. As per lad's answer, select * is not a good idea.

Comment: @StuartLC I do not recommend this aproach `DROP-CREATE` when you have custom privileges set to users. When you drop and recreate you have to recreate permissions. `CREATE-ALTER` is safer/easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax indicates that it is `SQL Server`. You could use dynamic sql:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('my_view') IS NULL
BEGIN
EXEC('CREATE VIEW dbo.my_view
      AS
      SELECT * 
      FROM dbo.my_table;');
END;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/CPNA44170)**</kbd>

The point is that [CREATE VIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> A view can be created only in the current database. **The CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch.** A view can have a maximum of 1,024 columns.

One way to achieve it is to use Dynamic-SQL to create new "context", where DDL is the first statment in batch.

Also I strongly recommend to specify all columns explicitly. Using `SELECT *` is common anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your reasons of doing it that way, you might be able to do it this way, which I have used in the past:

```
if object_id('my_view') is null
drop view my_view
go
create view dbo.my_view as
select * from dbo.my_table;
go
```

You may not really want to drop the view for one reason or another, but this works for me for a similar goal.

Edit: Ninja'd by @StuartLC, wasn't trying to steal his suggestion.